# Can I have a rails resource with the same name as the joosy namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming, joosy

I'm creating a todos app to play around with Joosy, and I want to have a rails model called `Todo` while also naming the joosy application `todo`. The following two lines create a conflict on `app/controllers/todos_controller.rb` no matter which order I enter them:

```
rails g todos title:string
rails g joosy:preloader todos
```

As a workaround, I've used `items` for my rails resource, but is there a way to use the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that by default current generator tries to make serving controller by name of an application. If you really want to use `todos` as Joosy app name, do the following:

1. Generate preloader
2. Manually rename controller that it generates to anything
3. Patch routes to reflect name modification
4. Now generate scaffolds

But I recommend you to rename the application to a thing like "front". It's going to be the only Joosy app among the Rails application so the name does not really matter.